# Fixing garage drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, garage

So I am planning to put an epoxy on my old garage floor, but before I do that, I want to get my drain taken care of. As you can see from the picture, its in pretty rough shape. How would I go about fixing this -- other than cleaning it out as much as possible? Do I have to just live with finding a grate that will fit? Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: What are we looking at here? Is the pipe metal or plastic? What size is it?

Answer (score 1):

Start out by cleaning out the drain. You're going to have to pull that junk up and out and avoid shoving it down any further. Once it's unclogged, plug it with a rag to prevent more stuff from falling into it. Chisel out the remains of the drain grate and what appears to be the packing between the pipe and the outside ring. Get a few bottles of concrete degreaser and clean all the grease and oil up as the epoxy will never bond to an oily surface. Once all that's done, pick up a drain grate at any plumbing supply store.